# Auto Save/Generate Report(PDF) to Server Disk

Tags: genexus

What do I need to do to save the report automatically on the server?
Currently it opens directly on the screen, but I need the physical path to forward to other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Rules tab you can specify a path. For example:

```
Output_file('c:\test\test.pdf', 'PDF');
```

The other way is to change in the PDFReport.ini the "OutputFileDirectory" property value.
Take a look to this [link](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?27500,PDFReport.ini%20file%20format,) for details.